# For loop in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

For example I have 2 data frames with 3 columns and I want to do

```
a = df[x].isin(df2[x])
b = df[x].isin(df2[y])
c = df[y].isin(df2[x])
d = df[y].isin(df2[x])
```

x and y is a column name of my two dataframes. How can I do it in loop and save each result ? So it can be elegant.
The result I expected more or less :

```
a; True = ddd
   False = eee
b; True = rrr
   False = fff
c; and so 
d; and so
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops:

```
columns = (x, y)
for a in columns:
    for b in columns: 
        df[a].isin(df2[b])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. but how if I want to save each result ?